# Node package.json Dependencies

Tags: node.js

New to Nodejs and looking at the dependencies section of the package.json file. Could someone explain to me what the `~` and `*` symbols do when setting the versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html):

The following range styles are supported:

- `1.2.3` A specific version. When nothing else will do. Note that build metadata is still ignored, so `1.2.3+build2012` will satisfy this range.
- `>1.2.3` Greater than a specific version.
- `<1.2.3` Less than a specific version. If there is no prerelease tag on the version range, then no prerelease version will be allowed either, even though these are technically "less than".
- `>=1.2.3` Greater than or equal to. Note that prerelease versions are NOT equal to their "normal" equivalents, so `1.2.3-beta` will not satisfy this range, but `2.3.0-beta` will.
- `<=1.2.3` Less than or equal to. In this case, prerelease versions ARE allowed, so `1.2.3-beta` would satisfy.
- `1.2.3 - 2.3.4` := `>=1.2.3` `<=2.3.4`
- `~1.2.3` := `>=1.2.3-0 <1.3.0-0` "Reasonably close to 1.2.3". When using tilde operators, prerelease versions are supported as well, but a prerelease of the next significant digit will NOT be satisfactory, so `1.3.0-beta` will not satisfy `~1.2.3`.
- `~1.2` := `>=1.2.0-0 <1.3.0-0` "Any version starting with 1.2"
- `1.2.x` := `>=1.2.0-0 <1.3.0-0`"Any version starting with 1.2"
- `~1` := `>=1.0.0-0 <2.0.0-0` "Any version starting with 1"
- `1.x` := `>=1.0.0-0 <2.0.0-0` "Any version starting with 1"
  Ranges can be joined with either a space (which implies "and") or a `||` (which implies "or").

Addendum:

`*` means any version.

Comment: thanks for this Brad - where is there mention of the `*` though?

Comment: @tommyd456 Added.  `*` means any version.

Comment: @tommyd456 Any.  `*` means you don't care what version you end up with.  Usually you'll get the latest stable, but if you care about version you should specify.

Comment: `=` at the begin works also as "A specific version"